# Searching for wifi connections

Tags: wireless

I have just installed Lubuntu on a friend's laptop. 
I have entered the wifi/router settings into network connections but I am unable to search to find wifi networks.

When I installed Lubuntu on my personal laptop I just left clicked the mouse on the wifi symbol (upside down triangle) in the bottom left of the task bar and various wifi networks appeared in the search.

The wifi LED is showing ok.

Comment: See http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7750/what-specific-things-should-i-include-in-my-question-if-i-have-a-problem-connect

Comment: Try `sudo service network-manager restart`

Answer (score 0):

First, silly, question: is there a hardware Wifi button and is it set to on? :-)

If that's not the case, you may need to find drivers for the card - some manufacturers haven't got open drivers in the kernel. Open a terminal, and do `sudo lspci`, then look for the brand and model in that list.

Comment: Hi, when I click on left hand mouse key on the wifi icon (triangle) all I get is VPN connection which is active )not greyed out) and (ethernet network and disconnected - both of these are greyed out) 

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/10/lubuntu-1310-perfect-for-netbooks.html

Please copy the above link into your browser and see the screen shot of the wifi connections (available networks) under Connecting to the internet... (this is what I should be seeing)

Comment: yes the wireless is switched to on. I checked this morning which network card (wifi card) this laptop has installed and it is a Broadcom BCM4321.I am unable to find the wifi tutorial for Lubuntu to add this network card. I have seen seen the wifi tutorial for Unbunuu on the internet.

Comment: Perhaps http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx is of use?